# Spring Boot - Custom De/Serializer

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

Want: Create SerDes for Cassandra's LocalDate into String.
Setup: Have a private LocalDateSerDes class with a Serializer and Deserializer internal class that both extend JsonDe/Serializer
Tried the following:

1. Adding to DTO fields with @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize (Works, but not wanted)
2. Used @JsonComponent set up via Baeldung's example (does not work)
3. Created a Module bean on my WebMvcConfigurationSupport configuration (does not work)
4. Implemented WebMvcConfigurationSupport.extendMessageConverters to add the Module to the instance of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (does not work)
5. Iterated through the list of converters, removed the instance, and replaced with the default converter builder code but with the module (does not work)

Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: I think you can take a look here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization
And here too : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization
But it ganna be more easy to others to understand more you need, if you can stcuture you code and you show them what you did :)

Comment: If you can post a little code to show what you're doing it would be helpful. I suspect that you're registering your custom serializer/deserializer on one instance of `ObjectMapper` but when you're trying to use it, a different `ObjectMapper` instance is being used. For example, if you're using Jackson in an API, your REST stack has a specific instance of `ObjectMapper` you need to register with.